# How do I code for the main method in OOP Java?

Tags: java, encapsulation

So, here's my assignment.

You are simply going to work with a point on a screen, and a circle on a screen as well. And let's consider them as the characters in the game. We are going to call both of these characters as Movable objects. Objects are said to be Movable if they can be moved around the screen. The following simple movements are allowed:

-public void moveLeft(); // moves the x to the left by 1 unit

-public void moveRight(); // moves the x to the right by 1 unit

-public void moveUp(); // moves the y 1 unit upward

-public void moveDown(); // moves the y 1 unit downward

-public void display(); // prints all the info about a Movable

Both Point and Circle characters are Movable.
The Point has an x coordinate and a y coordinate. The Circle has a Point (representing its center) and a radius (for our purpose this is an int). The attributes may all be set to public.

-It goes without saying that Point and Circle should implement all the methods of Movable
since they are Movable objects.

-The screen where the characters are going to move around is a 2-dimensional screen with
coordinates (0,0) as its top-left corner and (200,200) as its bottom-right corner.

-Make sure that when the characters are moving on the screen, they do not go out of the
screen, especially with the Circle character since it has a radius involved.

-For the display() function, in Point, print Point: (x,y) and in Circle, print Circle: (x,y), r.

Input Format
The first input is either 1 (a Point) or 2 (a Circle). If it is a Point, 2 non-negative integers follow, if it is a Circle, 3 non-negative integers follow, the 3rd being the radius. Then a positive integer m is read representing the number of operations that have to be performed followed by the operations themselves. - 1 - moveLeft() - 2 - moveRight() - 3 - moveUp() - 4 - moveDown()

Input Sample

```
1

0 0

5

4

4

2

2 

1
```

Output Sample

```
Point:·(1,2)
```

This is missing the main method, but then again I don't know how to code for it. I have a hard understanding about coding for main method, can you help me?

```
    interface Moveable
{
   public void moveLeft();
   public void moveRight();
   public void moveUp();
   public void moveDown();
   public void display();
}

class Point implements Moveable

{

public static final int MAX_CHAR=200;
protected int x;
protected int y;

public Point(int X, int Y) { x=X; y=Y; }
public int GetX() { return(x); }
public int GetY() { return(y); }


Point(Point p) { this.x = p.x; this.y=p.y; } //copy constructor

//implements Moveable

public void moveLeft()
{
    if (x>0)
{
    x--;
}

else{

System.out.println("BUMP:Bounces off left side");

}

}

public void moveRight()
{

    if (x<Point.MAX_CHAR)

{
    x++;
}

else
{
    System.out.println("BUMP:Bounces off right side");
}

}
public void moveUp()
{
if (y>0)
{
    y--;
}

else

{
    System.out.println(" BUMP: Bounces off top ");
}
}
public void moveDown()
{
if (y<Point.MAX_CHAR)
{
    y++;
}
else
{
    System.out.println(" BUMP: Bounces off bottom");
}

}
@Override public String toString()

{

return(
new String("Point:(" +x + "," +y+")")

);

}

public void display()

{

System.out.println(toString());

}

}

/*****************************************************************************/

class Point implements Moveable

{

public static final int MAX_CHAR=200;
protected int x;
protected int y;

public Point(int X, int Y) { x=X; y=Y; }
public int GetX() { return(x); }
public int GetY() { return(y); }

Point(Point p) { this.x = p.x; this.y=p.y; } //copy constructor

//implements Moveable

public void moveLeft()

{

    if (x>0)

{

    x--;

}

else
{
    System.out.println("BUMP:Bounces off left side");

}

}

public void moveRight()

{

if (x<Point.MAX_CHAR)
{

    x++;
}
else
{
    System.out.println("BUMP:Bounces off right side");
}

}

public void moveUp()

{
if (y>0)
{
    y--;

}

else

{
    System.out.println(" BUMP: Bounces off top ");

}

}

public void moveDown()

{
if (y<Point.MAX_CHAR)
{
    y++;
}

else
{

    System.out.println(" BUMP: Bounces off bottom");

}

}



@Override public String toString()

{

return(

new String("Point:(" +x + "," +y+")")

);

}

public void display()

{

System.out.println(toString());

}
}

/******************************************************************/

class Point implements Moveable

{



public static final int MAX_CHAR=200;
protected int x;
protected int y;

public Point(int X, int Y) { x=X; y=Y; }
public int GetX() { return(x); }
public int GetY() { return(y); }


Point(Point p) { this.x = p.x; this.y=p.y; } //copy constructor



//implements Moveable

public void moveLeft()

{

if (x>0)

{

    x--;

}

else

{

System.out.println("BUMP:Bounces off left side");

}

}



public void moveRight()

{

if (x<Point.MAX_CHAR)

{

x++;

}

else

{

System.out.println("BUMP:Bounces off right side");

}

}



public void moveUp()

{

if (y>0)

{
    y--;
}

else

{
System.out.println(" BUMP: Bounces off top ");

}

}


public void moveDown()

{
if (y<Point.MAX_CHAR)
{
    y++;

}

else
{
    System.out.println(" BUMP: Bounces off bottom");
}

}

@Override public String toString()

{

return (new String("Point:(" +x + "," +y+")"));

}

public void display()

{

System.out.println(toString());

}
}
```

Comment: "This is my code, but when I run it nothing shows up(not even an error). What's wrong with this?" ehm ... how exactly do you run this? You have no entry point for your application (main method) so it can't be run.

Comment: @Stultuske the assignment is to run the program :) op needs main method!!

Comment: Yes, I'm having a problem in creating the main method. I have a hard understanding of it. Can you help me?

Comment: @AshishMishra yes, yet the OP states that whe (s)he runs the code, nothing shows, so, how is it ran?

Comment: @Emi you need to write a main method with a scanner, accepting doubles. Then based on conditional statements checking the values you inputted, the right method(s) have to be executed

Comment: @Stultuske If its okay, can you code it for me?

Comment: I think you made a mistake. You posted the code for class `Point` three times and you didn't post the code for class `Circle`. By the way, did you write the code that you posted? Or was it given to you as part of the assignment? (Be honest!)

Comment: "_can you code it for me_" – Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @Abra All 3 are the same, they are attempted code for the class file.

Comment: Can I? yes, Am I going to do so? No. If you don't know how to write an appropriate main method you shouldn't be writing an implementation of your logic. Check this link in order to start with your main method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html